# How to solve the issue with downloading in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

guys.
I am using a local server with laravel framework and trying to download file.
I tried many cases but nothing works for me.

The thing is I get no errors.

Downloading wont`t start but in response I have something like this:

```
�

���JFIF��;CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), quality = 95��C      
���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br�  
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz���������������������������������������������������������������������������    
���w!1AQaq"2�B����   #3R�br�
$4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������?���!�A���I��+�P�sB���i��?�Y�L��iG���B���Ap�����J;���;}ic=F{R�Z��
�$��z�q��~�p8�h�v?A@��;����t�@�Fx��Ǯq�S#<������qS-
```

That what I used:
tried this way:

```
$file = 'D:\Server\OpenServer\domains\memo.ru\public\img\avatars\\'.$file_name;
$filePath=$file;
```

and this:

```
$file = "http://example.com/img/avatars/1457091259.png";
```

1.

```
    set_time_limit(0);
    $file = @fopen($filePath, 'rb');
    while ( !feof($file) ) {
        print( @fread($file,1024*8) );
        //ob_flush();
        flush();
    }
```

2

```
    $handle = fopen($filePath, 'rb');
    $buffer = '';
    while ( !feof($handle) ) {
        $buffer = fread($handle, 4096);
        echo $buffer;
        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }
    fclose($handle);
```

3

```
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    //header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
```

4

```
$real_path = 'D:\Server\OpenServer\domains\example.com\public\img\avatars\\';
$file = "http://example.com/img/avatars/1457091259.png";

$url  = 'http://example.com/img/avatars/'.$tmpFileName;
$path = $real_path.$tmpFileName;

$fp = fopen($path, 'w');

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Laravel 5 then this would be the most straightforward way:

```
public function download()
{

    $file = base_path(). "public/img/avatars/1457091259.png";

    $name = "Human Name For File.jpg";

    $headers = ['Content-Type: application/octet-stream'];

    return Response::download($file, $name, $headers);
}
```

Just name sure you have `use Response` at the top before the `class`

The `application/octet-stream` header should force the browser to download the file rather than display it in the browser window.

Comment: I have "use Response". Browser doesn`t start the downloading. Maybe are there another settings?

Comment: Which URL are you accessing in the browser and what error is displayed?

Comment: No errors. Just this ( i.yapx.ru/yO0.png ) in response.

Comment: For my example to work you'd need to go to i.yapx.ru/yO0.png/download. Try that first and when it's working you can go on to add the filename as a variable.

Comment: For your example: FileNotFoundException in File.php line 41:
The file "D:\Server\OpenServer\domains\example.com/public/img/avatars/1457158431.png" does not exist

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$fileName);
echo readfile($file);
die();
```

Comment: $file = 'https://assets.easypost.com/img/carriers/tnt-logo-ca.png';
header('Content-Type: image/png');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=test.png');
echo readfile($file);
die(); this code surely works for me set it in a .php file and call that using http://localhost/demo.php

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following quite successfully for downloading / sending files - perhaps it will be of use to you?

Call it like:

```
call_user_func( 'send_file', 'myfile.docx', 'c:/temp/document.docx' );


function send_file( $name, $strPath ) {
    if( file_exists( $strPath ) ) { 
        if( !is_file( $strPath ) or connection_status()!=0 ) { return FALSE;    }

        header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
        header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", mktime(date("H")+2, date("i"), date("s"), date("m"), date("d"), date("Y")))." GMT");
        header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s")." GMT");
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Length: ".(string)( filesize( $strPath ) ) );
        header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename={$name}");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");

        if( $file = fopen( $strPath, 'rb' ) ) {
            while( !feof( $file ) and ( connection_status()==0 ) ) {
                print( fread( $file, 1024*8 ) );
                flush();
            }
            fclose( $file );
        }
        clearstatcache();
        return( ( connection_status()==0 ) and !connection_aborted() );
    }
}
```